# In md-contact-chips How to select the Selected Items

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Can anybody tell me that how to use  `md-contact-chips`  to push in an array to all selected Items. I tried with `md-on-select="getChipInfo($chip)" md-on-remove="removeChip($chip)"`

but its not working for me.

Comment: I think `md-on-select` is under `md-tab`, not in `md-contact-chips` [read this](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTab)

Answer (score 0):

See this:

https://angular-material.firebaseapp.com/1.0.0/api/directive/mdContactChips/
http://flowersinthesand.github.io/material/#/demo/material.components.chips/

Use the attribute ng-model="myProperty" and in the controller this code:

```
$scope.myProperty = new Array({value: "A", id: 1}, {value: "B", id: 2});
$scope.$watch("myProperty ", function (newValue, oldValue) {
// my code on change
});
```